# Publish .net core 2 Api project without Microsift dlls

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

When I Publish my net core project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Authors>Arthur Vaverko</Authors>
    <Company>Home</Company>
    <Product>MyApi</Product>
    <PackageId>MyApi</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    <Description>My package</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2017</Copyright>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Home.MyPackage" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2"/>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

running the following

`dotnet publish -o build`

I get the following list of dlls... (partial...)

> ..... de es fr it ja KalturaClient.Net.Core.dll ko log4net.config
>   log4net.dll Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup.dl
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServicesIntegration.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions.dll .... ....

How can I publish only the dlls that I need because the target machine contains the ISS `DotNetCore.2.0.5-WindowsHosting` and if required i would rather install the .net core sdk as well instead of publishing a ~48Mb project every time.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the support page for `dotnet publish`, it says there are the possible options:

```
dotnet publish [<PROJECT>] [-c|--configuration] 
[-f|--framework] [--force] [--manifest] 
[--no-dependencies] [--no-restore] [-o|--output] 
[-r|--runtime] [--self-contained] [-v|--verbosity] 
[--version-suffix]
```

The default value for `--self-contained` is true when runtime is specified.

When `--self-contained` is set to true, implicitly or explicitly, it publishes framework files with it to make it - as the word suggests - "self contained". When you set it to false, it will only publish "your" dlls.

More information about command can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x

you find the difference between "Framework-dependent deployment" & "Self-contained deployment" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index

---

So coming to your current issue, if you are seeing runtime packages in the published folder, there are 2 possibilities.

1. you are specifying runtime with `-r | --runtime <RUNTIME>` option
2. you are explicitly setting `--self-contained` to true

Answer (score 0):

You can try dotnet publish -c Release